# Why GnuPG decryption speed is so low

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

speed of decryption is 20 times more than encryption!result show encryption time is 14.238579760014545(1000 times) and for decryption time is 339.19246241397923(1000 times).
CPU : Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8 
RAM : 15.6 GiB 
OS : Ubuntu 18

```py
    import timeit

    mysetup = '''
    import gnupg

    '''
    encrypt_code = '''
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='gpghome')
    text="""Or kind rest bred with am shed then. In raptures building an bringing be. Elderly is detract tedious assured private so to visited. Do travelling companions contrasted it. Mistress strongly remember up to. Ham him compass you proceed calling detract. Better of always missed we person mr. September smallness northward situation few her certainty something. 

    An sincerity so extremity he additions. Her yet there truth merit. Mrs all projecting favourable now unpleasing. Son law garden chatty temper. Oh children provided to mr elegance marriage strongly. Off can admiration prosperous now devonshire diminution law. """
    status = gpg.encrypt(text, recipients=['testgpguser@mydomain.com'])
    '''

    decrypt_code = '''
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='gpghome')
    enc_text=b"-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\\n\\nhQEMA0GPN4kKbscAAQf/RNDIh8LqxJi572Kd330Fx0DmYVMBnLy8Bcn0z4vZNpIM\\njkXdnH3aqOGD+/2ToIGhgGZue46ZDc/J2pdTze1wJsP20E1q04v/J3lihRa368cc\\nYfD4Za0egt7mY1LeW7ABXzqQ3Ni1hLP97wOHe1WSfM7csOXv4xfIREM2e6IOvJ4C\\nwIrgReQbHNbEtLw3NxINevj8YVPuILJp6IDcbDtieLexTS2y66j7GazSDZRZgHLi\\nu4qE8P4Oq6sf1f0YSQI4oeQrtVKEfIIFyb/SNag1FrqRLjF3TGM22OUIIoCleYdN\\nzyv1tEeulU9h1+QYogSa7BxYB9pmW6keA8d/QdkG09I7AXXVdGL9mq0cLVqReXyC\\nqCDvnejwcM8E5ceHZR8KGm+9jVB+hcxC2HJ3TABnFNUeHMknVvLoFP9xMe0=\\n=KSv4\\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\\n"
    status = gpg.decrypt(enc_text, passphrase='my passphrase')
    '''


    print(timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=encrypt_code, number=1000))
    print(timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=decrypt_code, number=1000))
```

Comment: `datetime` is a bad way to benchmark code. Use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). And leave the `open` calls outside the timed code; it has nothing to do with en-/decryption and may add significant time to the result.

Comment: You're still benchmarking the `open` call too. Make that part of the `setup` (e.g. read the file contents into a variable or a `BytesIO`—I don't know whether `gpg` will accept a `bytes` as input or wants a file-like object). And leave the `number` at its default, certainly more than `1`.

Comment: So you switched to timeit in your code, but the time measures are the same ?  Please update your question to reflect the new methode's.

Comment: Question updated.timeit used and IO operations removed from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your decrypt takes a passphrase as opposed to the encrypt. This is because the private key is in an encrypted keyring. The key deviation process used on this passphrase is properly an iterative process that takes some time.

It might be this one: [iterated-and-salted-s2k](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-06.html#iterated-and-salted-s2k)

Comment: without passphrase encryption time is 11.165737244009506(1000 times) and decryption time is 27.76454692403786 (1000 times)(10 time better). What is risk of remove passphrase?

Answer (score 2):

GPG uses RSA, and according to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57205/why-is-rsa-decryption-slow) it is perfectly normal for RSA decryption to be slower than encryption, because the private key needs to be long, but the public key doesn't necessarily.

Comment: I want use it for send camera frame to remote server and just want to know my benchmark is normal or there is any tips for increase speed.

Comment: We use hybrid encryption for solve RSA speed problem.As I tested RSA2048 speed for encrypt AES key is  0:00:00.001047 and for decryption it`s time is 0:00:00.002715 so bottleneck is another location.

Comment: Make sure that you use RSA with CRT that can speed up to 4-times.